# Why does fs.existsSync always return false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to check if a file is exist. So, I apply fs.existsSync() function.
But, the problem is this function always return false (not exit).

Written below is my code.

Thank you in advance!

[ My Environment ]

- Ubuntu
- Node.js version 16.14.0

```
const fs = require('fs')

const getProvinceByCountry = country => {

    const filePath = `../../config/province/${country}.json`
    const fileExist = fs.existsSync(filePath)

    if (!fileExist) { 
        console.log('File does not exist') 
    } else {
        console.log('File exists') 
    }
}

// Result : File does not exists.
// existsSync() always returns false even if the path and the file name are correct.
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log()` the file path to make sure it is the right one, since you are relying on a relative path?

Comment: Isn't it working correctly? If the file exists it will always go to `else` block because your if condition is `!fileExist`. If file doesn't exist it will go to `if` block. I don't understand the issue here? Even your console log says - File exists

Comment: @ShivamSood oh... my mistake. The result was 'File does not exist' not 'File exist'

Comment: @Ben the file path is correct.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be too many variables in this issue, one of it has to be incorrect. Either Path is incorrect. `Country` parameter doesn't have correct value. Try proving absolute path and console.log the country parameter to check if you are getting correct value.

Comment: The code is correct and works. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Node.js v16.13.1. Either the path is wrong or you don't have the necessary permissions to read the file. Example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xehahs?file=index.js

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I've solve the problem. What I did is use path.join.

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `../../config/province/${country}.json`)
```